# Responsive web design fixed widths

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to convert my website into responsive design.. What I am planning is to have three  layouts each with width 1024(present version) and maybe a 600px width version and 300 px width version.. I am new to responsive designs so I want to know what is the best choice for these widths?

one is 1024 px(width of the main-container)

As I resize below a width of 1024 px I resize the webpage to 600 px

and on resize of browser below 600px I will make it 300px.

My question is what is the best choice for these width? Are 600px and 300px good enough or please suggest what is best option?

Comment: Fixing it for 1024,600,300 would make it non-responsive actually.. Use bootstrap to create responsive websites, the widths are by-default handled by the styles. you just need to use the right classes. Check out http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: This sounds more like [adaptive web design](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/what-is-the-difference-between-responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design/) (AWD) than responsive web design (RWD). With responsive web design, media queries are used with fluid layouts (percentages instead of pixels). With adaptive web design, specific device sizes are targeted with media queries and then a fixed (pixel based) layout is applied within the media query range.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off to design for screen-width using percentages rather than fixed px sizes. There are lots of grid systems you can use.

Have a look at this thread for an example;

[Full width list in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541695/full-width-list-in-css/21542045#21542045)